# JFrame not displaying panel content

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jtextfield

I just got started learning JFrame and is trying to create a frame containing JLabels and JTextFields frame using grouplayout, but the contents inside my panel aren't appearing when I run the program.
All help is appreciated.

```
    package practice;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class Boxc {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("---------------------(-_-)---------------------"); 
        JLabel headText = new JLabel("Teach Me"); 

        //head text
        headText.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
        headText.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        headText.setFont(headText.getFont().deriveFont(20f));




        frame.setVisible(true); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(700, 500);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //Center start position
        frame.add(headText);

        //panel 1
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(panel1);
        panel1.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);


        JLabel uInput = new JLabel("When You Type:");
        JTextField uText = new JTextField("Enter Here");
        JLabel iReply = new JLabel("I Reply:");
        JTextField iText = new JTextField("Enter Here");

        GroupLayout.SequentialGroup hGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();
        hGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup().
                addComponent(uInput).addComponent(iText));
        hGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup().
                addComponent(uText).addComponent(iText));
       layout.setHorizontalGroup(hGroup);





        frame.add(panel1);
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is weird.

It all has to do with the ordering of your JFrame methods. You must ALWAYS do `frame.setVisible(true);` at the end, preferably as the last line of code in whatever you're using to initiate the JFrame. In that case,

```
frame.setVisible(true); 
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(700, 500);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //Center start position
    frame.add(headText);
```

would be changed to

```
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(700, 500);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //Center start position
    frame.add(headText);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: ignore the changing from/to. Put the `frame.setVisible(true);` after `frame.add(panel1);`.

Comment: The panel1 section still isn't appearing after I switched the position. Thanks for the advice though. Also, I believe it has to do with the panel1 section itself, as the rest of the code, such as the headText, shows on the frame.

Comment: Did you put `frame.setVisible(true);` after `frame.add(panel);`? I'm sure you did, I'm just making sure because your problem sounds a lot like it stems from incorrect placement of the `frame.setVisible(true);`.

Comment: I tried that, but I was met with a great amount of errors, the first few includes: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.swing.JLabel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=8388608,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=,text=When You Type:,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER] is not attached to a vertical group
 at javax.swing.GroupLayout.checkComponents(Unknown Source)

Comment: pretty sure i made some error in my panel1 section, not too familiar with grouplayout.

Comment: @X and Y and also, add your `headText` to `panel1` instead of the frame. I'm pretty sure the panel will just cover it up once you get it working.

Comment: @X and Y oh, I know the problem. you need to call the method `label.setBounds(x, y, width, height);`. Try that. (this method sets the width, height, x, and y position of the JLabel. It seems you have not done that.) (also, `label` that I have referenced is meant to be replaced with your desired label to change the bounds of)

Comment: For all the labels or just one? Also what would be a recommended bound.

Comment: @X and Y all JLabels. X and Y is relative to the top left corner of the JFrame, and the actual JLabel's "middle"  is the top left corner of the JLabel as well. so I'd recommend `label.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);` for the first one, `label.setBounds(50, 0, 50, 50);` for the second, `label.setBounds(100, 0, 50, 50);` for the third,  and `label.setBounds(150, 0, 50, 50);` for the fourth. This is just to give you an idea of the relatives of JLabels to JFrames, from there you can experiment where you want your JLabels and stuff.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll keep testing until I get the problem fixed.

Comment: @X and Y you might want to also, as I am not the biggest pro at groupLayout, you might want to try and add your group layout to your panel. If that doesn't work, trying  `panel1.setLayout(layout);` might also work out. If none of these work, then that's as far as my knowledge goes. I apologize if none of these work. `layout` called in `panel.setLayout(layout);` of course stands for the name of your layout, which I don't quite remember.

Comment: I changed to gridlayout and got it working, much easier for me. Thank you for your help nonetheless :).